# How to convert arcsec to Mpc using python astropy?

Tags: python, astropy

I need to convert from arcsec to mega parsec scale for the following quantities:

```
a = 737.28 # arcsec
z = 0.3 # redshift
d = ? # Mpc

I am using flat lambdaCDM using parameters
H0 = 67.8
omega_m = 0.308
```

Cosmology used: Ade et al 2016
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01589.pdf   table1 2013F(DS)

I have tried this so far,

```
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM
import astropy.units as u

cosmo = FlatLambdaCDM(H0=70, Om0=0.3)
cosmo.luminosity_distance(z=0.3)

# I am not sure how to convert arcsec to Mpc here.
```

Alternatives:
http://arcsec2parsec.joseonorbe.com/index.html

This works and gives 3.38 Mpc, but I can not simply cite a website, it is desired to reproduce the result using python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the distance, you need to multiply angular diameter distance by angular size.

l = D_A(z) × θ

Reference: http://arcsec2parsec.joseonorbe.com/about.html

```py
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM
import numpy as np
cosmo = FlatLambdaCDM(H0=67.8, Om0=0.308)

# angular diameter distance in Mpc
d_A = cosmo.angular_diameter_distance(z=0.3)
theta = 737.28 # arcsec

# pi radian = 180 degree ==> 1deg = pi/180 ==> 1arcsec = pi/180/3600
theta_radian = theta * np.pi / 180 / 3600

# arc length = radius * angle
distance_Mpc = d_A * theta_radian

print(distance_Mpc) # 3.3846475 Mpc
```

**UPDATE**
As suggested in comments, we can also use astropy units,

```py
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM
import numpy as np
from astropy import units as u
cosmo = FlatLambdaCDM(H0=67.8, Om0=0.308)

d_A = cosmo.angular_diameter_distance(z=0.3)
print(d_A) # 946.9318492873492 Mpc

theta = 737.28*u.arcsec
distance_Mpc = (theta * d_A).to(u.Mpc, u.dimensionless_angles()) # unit is Mpc only now

print(distance_Mpc) # 3.384745689510495 Mpc
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `theta = 737.28*u.arcsec; distance_Mpc = (theta * d_A).to(u.Mpc, u.dimensionless_angles())`, which uses an equivalency and is a little more general.